# Como passar parâmetros bidirecional para uma diretiva AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net, angularjs-directives, binding

Preciso que o atributo `parameterID="{{autor.ID}}` que na diretiva é `parameterID: '@'` seja atualizado assim que for mudado, ou seja, preciso que o bind seja biderecional, vi em varios lugares dizendo para usar o `parameterID: '='` mas só que me deparo com esse erro.

> ERRO: angular.js:14700 Error: [$compile:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=parameterID&p2=navigator
>       at angular.js:88
>       at x (angular.js:10619)
>       at q (angular.js:10632)
>       at angular.js:16659
>       at m.$digest (angular.js:18253)
>       at m.$apply (angular.js:18531)
>       at l (angular.js:12547)
>       at s (angular.js:12785)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.y.onload (angular.js:12702)
>
> Chamada do componente Navigator

```html
<navigator edit="false" create="true" view="false" urlCreate="/Autor/Create" urlEdit="/Autor/Editar/{{autor.ID}}" urlList="/Autor" registroCadastradoComSucesso="{{registroCadastradoComSucesso}}" parameterID="{{autor.ID}}">

    </navigator>
```

> Diretiva

```js
angular.module('app').directive('navigator', [function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: './AngularJS/view/Navigator/Navigator.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            edit: '@edit',
            create: '@create',
            view: '@view',
            urlCreate: '@urlCreate',
            urlEdit: '@urlEdit',
            urlList: '@urlList',
            parameterID: '@parameterID',
            registroCadastradoComSucesso: '@registroCadastradoComSucesso'
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.urlCreate = attrs.urlcreate;
            $scope.urlEdit = attrs.urledit;
            $scope.urlList = attrs.urllist;

            $scope.edit = attrs.edit;
            $scope.create = attrs.create;
            $scope.view = attrs.view;

            $scope.registroCadastradoComSucesso = attrs.registrocadastradocomsucesso;
            $scope.parameterID = attrs.parameterid;
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.remove = $scope.$parent.delete;
        }
    }

}]);
```

> Pagina HTML do navigator

```html
<!-- BARRA DE NAVEGAÇÃO -->
<div>
    <ol class="breadcrumb" ng-show="create">
        <li ng-if="!registroCadastradoComSucesso" class="active"> Novo </li>
        <li ng-if="registroCadastradoComSucesso"><a ng-href="#!{{urlCreate}}"> Novo </a></li>
        <li ng-if="!registroCadastradoComSucesso" class="active"> Editar </li>
        <li ng-if="registroCadastradoComSucesso"><a ng-href="#!{{urlEditar}}"> Editar </a></li>
        <li ng-if="!registroCadastradoComSucesso" class="active"> Deletar </li>
        <li ng-if="registroCadastradoComSucesso"><a ng-href="#!{{urlDelete}}" ng-click="remove(1)"> Deletar </a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#!{{urlList}}"> Listar Autores </a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Tente passar a variável diretamente, sem os brackets: `parameterID="autor.ID"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já viu se o {{autor.id}} tem algum valor ou se ele vem undefined? 
Testa com valor estático e vê se ele funciona.

Um detalhe que eu vi na documentação é que no .JS da diretiva você usa o padrão camel-case mas no HTML você substitui o camel-case por hífens **(urlEdit** ficaria **url-edit** no HTML)

```html
 <navigator edit="false" create="true" view="false" url-create="/Autor/Create" url-edit="/Autor/Editar/{{autor.ID}}" url-list="/Autor" registro-cadastrado-com-sucesso="{{registroCadastradoComSucesso}}" parameter-id="{{autor.ID}}">

    </navigator>
```

**Dá um control-f "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" [aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**